# How to get data from subcollection in firestore using flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

i tried this .Sorry im a beginner.i cant put a document I'd in the unique I'd place as there are multiple documents under which userProducts collection comes. moreover new documents will keep generating as users increase.Inside every new document generated there's a subcollection created called userProducts.Is any other way ?

```
     Future  getProducts() async {
    var firestore = Firestore.instance;
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await firestore.collection('products'). documents (doc id).collection('userProducts').getDocuments();
//          .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
    return snapshot.documents;
```

Comment: Have you tried using ```firestore.collection('products/userId/userProducts').getDocuments()```?
The collection method takes a path to a collection or a subcollection. Assuming you have a collection named products, you must have a document with some random ID assigned by firestore. You need to put that id instead of userId in the method above.

Comment: You can try `firestore.collection('products').document(unique id).collection('userProducts').getDocuments()`

Comment: But i cant put a document I'd in the unique I'd place as there are multiple documents under which userProducts collection comes. moreover new documents will keep generating as users increase.Inside every new document generated there's a subcollection created called userProducts.Is any other way ?